# one loop correlator in ads cft

Tags: string-theory, ads-cft

Is there any example of explicit one loop computation for Witten diagrams?
It seems like it will be hard to compute for even for a simple $\phi^4$ theory in the bulk.

Comment: Vibert had posted an answer which is really a comment. However, it links to a valuable resource, so I'll put it down here (remove this comment if you convert the answer to a comment): "It's done in the Penedones paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.1485."